# Estimating a Power Spectrum from a Time Series

Tags: fft, power-spectral-density

What are the best ways to estimate the power spectrum of a given time series?  Any pointers to review articles or book chapters would be appreciated.

A little more information: When estimating a power spectrum from a time series, I typically use Welch's method (matlab command pwelch) with the default parameters.  My understanding is that this is standard practice in the community, but that it became so in the days when computing power was limited.  With modern computing abilities, are there better (more accurate) ways to estimate a power spectrum? What are the differences between the methods?

Comment: @JasonR Indeed, this question appears to address most of what I wanted to know.  Somehow I missed it in my initial search.  Thanks!